# Incrementing Label Value when a button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have tried converting using CInt, TryParse, Convert.Int32, etc but nothing worked. I just need to display the total votes of the candidated when a button btnVote is clicked and display the result when I click btnResult. I've tried searching on the net also but still no luck so I came up to this website and hopefully I could solve my problem with my program in VB.net

Below is my code:

```
Public Class Presidential_Election

    Private Sub btnVote_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVote.Click
        If cboCandidates.Text = "NOLI" Then
            lblNoli.Text = Integer.Parse(lblNoli.Text) + 1
        ElseIf cboCandidates.Text = "VAL" Then
            lblVal.Text = (CInt(lblVal.Text) + 1).ToString
        ElseIf cboCandidates.Text = "LESTER" Then
            lblLester.Text = CInt(lblLester.Text) + 1
        ElseIf cboCandidates.Text = "GWAPO" Then
            lblGwapo.Text = CInt(lblGwapo.Text) + 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnResult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnResult.Click
        lblNoli.Visible = True
        lblVal.Visible = True
        lblLester.Visible = True
        lblGwapo.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you should be calling the ToString method in all cases, which turning `Option Strict On`, as you should, would force you to do, it looks like it should work.  What about it doesn't work?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: What happens when you try the 2nd one: (CInt(lblVal.Text)+1).ToString?  BTW, did you put () after ToString?

Comment: What is the starting value for the label text properties?

Comment: All of the functions I used above says "InvalidCastException Unhandled"

@melanie, still it didn't work. But I haven't tried put() yet because it's my first time to hear that method. I'm a newbie in vb.net

Comment: @Steven, the starting is "", I guess. I haven't initialized them, I just used them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set the label text to be `0` at the beginning, using `CInt` would definitely throw an error. You have two options :

- set all labels text to 0 and keep using `CInt`, or
- use Val()

Example :

```
lblGwapo.Text = Val(lblGwapo.Text) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set an integer counter for each candidate. Set these to 0 and then increment them as they receive a vote. When you display the results just bind the text of the label to its respective counter and make it visible. This way, you don't have to keep referencing label.text.